# Datastream configuration not working for Cloud SQL PostgreSQL as source and BigQuery as destination

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-datastream

I wanted to quickly give a try to datastream from cloud SQL PotgreSQL to BigQuery. I created a test Cloud SQL instance where I use `postgres` who is already as cloudsqlsuperuser. But the wizard provided by Datastream is not helping: part of the provided statements are not working.

Here are the steps I followed.

[image]

1. I activated `cloudsql.logical_decoding` flag as required by the `Enable logical replication on the database` Step

[image]

2. For the `Create a publication and a replication slot` step, I succesfully ran the first command `CREATE PUBLICATION DATASTREAM_PUBLICATION FOR ALL TABLES;`
   But the second `SELECT PG_CREATE_LOGICAL_REPLICATION_SLOT('DATASTREAM_SLOT_NAME', 'PGOUTPUT');` failed
3. First I had this error : `ERROR:  must be superuser or replication role to use replication slots SQL state: 42501`
   I fixed with this command `ALTER USER postgres WITH REPLICATION;`
4. When I re ran `SELECT PG_CREATE_LOGICAL_REPLICATION_SLOT('DATASTREAM_SLOT', 'PGOUTPUT');` Then I had this error : `ERROR:  replication slot name "DATASTREAM_SLOT_NAME" contains invalid character HINT:  Replication slot names may only contain lower case letters, numbers, and the underscore character. SQL state: 42602`
   I fixed it using lower case for the slot name.
5. When I ran command `SELECT PG_CREATE_LOGICAL_REPLICATION_SLOT('datastream_slot', 'PGOUTPUT');` I got this error: `ERROR:  could not access file "PGOUTPUT": No such file or directory SQL state: 58P01`
   I fixed it by putting `PGOUTPUT` in lower case and re ran : `SELECT PG_CREATE_LOGICAL_REPLICATION_SLOT('datastream_slot', 'pgoutput');`

[image]

6. For the `Create Datastream User` step I could run : `CREATE USER datastream_user WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '*****';`

but Fail to run: `GRANT RDS_REPLICATION TO datastream_user;` with this error `role "rds_replication" does not exist SQL state: 42704`

I could run `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO datastream_user;`

I could run `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO datastream_user;`

I failed to run `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public` with this error : `ERROR:  syntax error at end of input LINE 1: ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public`

I failed to run `GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO datastream_user;` with this error: `ERROR:  relation "tables" does not exist SQL state: 42P01`

I dont have solutions for the failed statement, but also these are the ones provided on the console for Datastream. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's apparently a mixup in the documentation steps in the UI. You can follow the [online docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/configure-your-source-postgresql-database#cloudsqlforpostgres-create-datastream-user) for the correct steps.

Specifically, in the CREATE PUBLICATION AND REPLICATION SLOT section you already figured it out, the correct command is:

```
SELECT PG_CREATE_LOGICAL_REPLICATION_SLOT('[REPLICATION_SLOT_NAME]', 'pgoutput');
```

And in the CREATE DATASTREAM USER section:

1. You don't need to run that first command (that's copy-pasted from RDS apparently, not relevant here)
2. Those last two "steps" should actually be a single command:

   ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA [MY_SCHEMA] GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO [MY_USER];

Comment: Thx Etai: the link to the documentation was very helpful.